# viewing documents in ios10 using qlpreviewcontroller or uidocumentinteractioncontroller

Tags: pdf, uidocumentinteraction, qlpreviewcontroller

does anyone know how to get rid of the thumbnail preview on the right side of viewer in ios10 when using qlpreviewcontroller or uidocumentinteractioncontroller.  covers part of document and seems to be permanent now.  i would take either it swiping off the page, being able to possibly inset the right side of the document, or adding a button to show or hide.  thanks for any help[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oOeE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. The user can tap the document to go full-screen and hide the thumbnails view.